# C# Newtonsoft - Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to fix a bug in a WinForms program I've made; I'm parsing a JSON string and then placing some of the results into various variables.

Sometimes, that particular element of the JSON is not there (for genuine reasons), so I've tried to handle that with the following code:

```
        int scriptVersion;
        if ((int)token.SelectToken("scriptVersion") == null)
        {
            scriptVersion = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            scriptVersion = (int)token.SelectToken("scriptVersion");
        }
```

This still throws a 'Value cannot be null' error in the second line of this code - should I be doing something different to handle occasions when the element is not present in the JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are casting the JToken to an int which is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Value types can't be null.

The [JToken.SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method returns a JToken object, which is a reference type, and thus can be null. Remove the cast, and it should work.

```
if (token.SelectToken("scriptVersion") == null)
```

Comment: @reviloSlater I'm glad my answer was helpful to you. Please mark it as the selected answer if your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares to know, the VB.Net version would read:

```
If token.SelectToken("scriptVersion") Is Nothing
```

The answer previously given was very helpful to me!